# Translation and / or rotation of two curves linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, self-learning

> Can i say that translation and / or rotation of a curve is linearly dependent of initial curve?

I was thinking of problem $\{ \sin x, \cos x\}$ are linearly dependent or not?
I found both are linearly dependent as constants are zero. Here $\cos x$  is just $\sin x$ curve shifted to right by 90 degrees right. It is just translation.

Then $\{x , x+1 \}$ both are linearly dependent.

Can i say that if i translate and or rotate a curve, both are linearly dependent? Is this generalized statement valid?

If i take another example, $\{ \sin x, \cos x, \tan x\}$, i am getting constants as zero which means linearly independent. But on other side, $\tan x = \frac {\sin x}{ \ cos x}$

Say in set of vectors {u,v,w}, if w = u/v, what can be said of linear dependence or independence?

Comment: What about shifting $\sin x$ by $360^\circ$?

Comment: shift by 180 or multiple of 180 will make sin x the same . Sin (180+x)= sin x

Comment: @peterwhy sir can you pls tell me whther am i right or not? what about w=u/v case?